# If I have a polynom $P(x)$, which zeros have the absolute value $q^{-(\frac{n-1}{2})}$. Why is this an accord to the Riemann hypothesis?

Tags: number-theory, riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

You can read the question above. So I'm really  " new in terms of Riemann hypothesis". I have read about the hypothesis in wikipedia. So I know the statement of the Hypothesis : The Riemann Zeta Function has its zeros  only at the negative even integers and  complex numbers with real part $\frac{1}{2}$. but I dont understand why the statement in the title is an accord for this hypothesis? $q$ is the number of elements in $F$, a finite field.

Thank you for explanation.

Comment: "I know that the Riemann Zeta Function has its zeros only at the negative even integers and complex numbers with real part $\frac12$." - Actually, nobody else knows that

Comment: This follows just by a change of variables. This gives the direct analogue of RH (which is for the usual zeta function), i.e., the fact that the roots of $Z_f(u)$ have absolute value $q^{-(n-1)/2}$ is equivalent to the fact that the roots of $\zeta_f(s)$ have real part $1/2$.

Comment: Very poor choice of words, Hagen von Eitzen. I meant I know the statement of the Hypothesis. @DietrichBurde oh.  Interesting. Do you have a source where I can see the change of variables for your claim ? :)

Comment: The change is $u=q^{-s}$. See "Weil conjectures" in Wikipedia, or at Terry Tao's [blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/weil-conjectures/), among other references. You should perhaps clarify your question and give a link to the article you were reading.

Comment: The Riemann Hypothesis says absolutely nothing about your polynomial $P$, so there's no possibility of there being a problem.

Comment: You should look at the local and global zeta and L-functions of elliptic curves (over finite fields and over $\mathbb{Q}$) and search about the analytic continuation, functional equations and Riemann hypothesis of each one (the local and global Riemann hypothesis are analytically unrelated, by you'll see why the wording are the same and how certain concepts transfer from the local to the global case)

Comment: Make what you mean by the question clear, then ask the question. As it stands, this is not in an answerable state.

Comment: My apologies. I see now that my question is not totally clear. Dietrich Burde, you have already answered my question with your two first comments. Thank you so much for your patience and understanding. You don't overreact, gave me an answer and hints for clearify my question. I will edit my question soon. So it will hopefully becomes clear for everyone. In general my questions are clear, but Im so clueless in this topic, that I wasnt able to make a good question. I will fix it soon. Sorry again. And thank you @reuns for your comment, too. Helps me a lot. :)